# kernel: nfs: nfsserver server not responding, timed out

Tags: redhat, nfs4

We have a NFS client which print in to messages this error:

```
kernel: nfs: server nfsserver not responding, timed out
```

it is printed about every minute. Normally I will think there had a communication issue or firewalled ports.

But here what is fun, the mounted NFS share works has expected, we cane R/W from it with the expected bandwidth!

Both server and client are RHEL7 the client mount it with the following mount options:

```
rw,vers=4.1,user,auto
```

the `timeo` and `retrans` are set to default (600 and 2). We have many clients point to this NFS Server and only one of them get this issue, all client mount the share with the same parameters and comes from different networks.

Comment: I am seeing the same log messages in the journal on one of our hosts. Did you ever figure out what was causing the messages and how to resolve it?

Comment: unfortunately no, we had never find the cause of this issue.